# I'm getting below error to build docker Image for app, using node 10.24.1-strentch image & trying to apt-get update & install Powershell

Tags: docker, debian

```
Ign:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Err:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
  503  Service Unavailable
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Err:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
  503  Service Unavailable
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Err:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
  503  Service Unavailable
Reading package lists...
W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
***
```

> W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates
> Release' does not have a Release file.
> **E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages
> 503  Service Unavailable
> E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages
> 503  Service Unavailable
> E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages
> 503  Service Unavailable**

---

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Comment: If the Debian archives are unavailable, there's nothing you can change in your local environment to change this, other than maybe pointing at a different mirror.